# How to buy a product using a various payments methods in python?

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments, payment, balanced-payments

I have a project that am working in and it almost done except one problem that i can't make or in fact i don't know how to make it done .

The client told me that he want to connect a various payments methods to his site , so lets consider that you are a user and you want to buy a product , inside your panel as a user there is a various banks or methods to buy this product, lets say:

- Qiwi wallet
- Webmoney
- Visa Card
- Master Card
- Yandex money

you can choose anyone of these to buy it .

Another thing is to show your balance inside the panel so to know whether you have enough money to pay or not, also he want that the user could charge money into his balance if he didn't have enough money.

There is a service called Stripe, which provide stuffs like that, but i 'am not really sure if it would help in any way, all i know about it is, you can make any payments using Master card or Visa card that's all .

Simply the issue is to know how to, pay with various payments methods, balance status and charge balance.

The project is written in `python` using `Flask framework` .

Please Please Please , bagging you all, how to make that work, or in a different way from where to start ?, which process should i follow ?, any help really truly would be tons appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe actually provides quite a [number of payment methods](https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-cards-and-payment-types-can-i-accept-with-stripe) but not all of the ones you've listed, so Stripe can definitely help, but you're going to have to implement multiple payment flows here - one for the methods that Stripe can handle, and one for each of the others - as part of your application.

With regards to the Stripe stuff, I'd suggest you have a read through the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs) to learn about getting started there.

Comment: Thanks for your interest sir, so, you mean by that something like API ?, i saw not all of them supporting python so far, for example qiwi have something more comfortable with php more than python if am not mistaking ! .

Comment: guys, any other suggestions ?